# How do I use the Wormhole detection system?

Tags: galaxy-on-fire-2

I recently became equipped with a system that apparently allows me to see areas that The Void are going to be opening wormholes in (and attacking).  Since I now need to get through one of the wormholes for a mission, I need to find a system where the void are about to attack so I can fly through their wormhole.

Trouble is, I don't actually see any indications of my map that look new.  How do I tell where The Void will be attacking soon?

[image: System Map]

[image: Galaxy Map]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You see a light blue swirl around the system, then when you go into the system map the swirl will be around one of the planets in it.

It does appear and disappear more or less at random and will turn up in another system later if you miss it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to be patient. The indication(s) of wormholes will appear. I had now problem identifying them.

Comment: Can you at least describe the indicators? This is not useful.

Comment: I think its a spiral, but I'm not sure. I would have left an comment but I can't :-(